# jsf обработать кнопку

Tags: java, jsf

Не погу понять, как сделать,чтобы при нажатии кнопки create pet можно было создать Pet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="growl" life="2000"/>

        <p:commandButton value="create pet" id="ajax" update="growl" actionListener="#{firstPage.buttonAction}"
                         styleClass="ui-priority-primary"/>


    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

сам класс Pet

```
@Entity(name = "PET")
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="pets", fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Treatment> treatments;

    public Collection<Treatment> getTreatments() {
        return treatments;
    }
}
```

этот класс  тоже нужен

```
public class FirstPage {

    @EJB
    private PetManager petManager;

    public void buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        petManager.createPet(FacesUtils.getUserId(), "NOT IMPLEMENTED YET");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете выражение:

```
actionListener="#{firstPage.buttonAction}"
```

Но ваш класс FirstPage никак не привязан к faces контексту. Чтобы привязать укажите над классом FirstPage следующие аннотации (первая привязывает к контексту, вторая определяет видимость бина):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "firstPage", eager = true)
@RequestScoped
public class FirstPage {
```

Если же вы используете несвежий jsf (версии < 2) то тогда вместо аннотаций вам необходимо прописать строки в faces-context.xml.

Кроме того в вашем примере посоветовал бы использовать action вместо actionListener.

Comment: хорошо, а что в самом хhtml надо прописать?

Comment: если вы про action то action="#{firstPage.buttonAction}" вместо листенера, а в остальном ничего

Comment: к сожалению это не работает

Comment: Возникает ошибка? Если да, приведите стэктрейс.

Comment: 21-Nov-2019 07:47:25.589 1100 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.log JSF1073: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException erfasst wÃ¤hrend Verarbeitung von RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Property [buttonAction] not found on type [com.eventim.petshop.view.FirstPage]
21-Nov-2019 07:47:25.590 1100 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.log Property [buttonAction] not found on type [com.eventim.petshop.view.FirstPage]

Comment: Если используете action то замените: buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) на buttonAction()

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: вы можете выложить код проекта на github?

Comment: вы были правы, ошибка была в импорте